# Do multithreads operate atomic variables in multiple cores without locking?

Tags: c

I have a question: I now use atomic operations in multiple threads. In the case of a single core, because it is a CPU, multiple threads do not need to lock when accessing the atomic variable v. however, in the case of a multi-core, because there are multiple CPUs and different threads running in different CPUs, there will be multiple threads operating the same atomic variable at the same time, It should be necessary to lock at this time. How can I lock it?

Pseudo code：

```
thread_1_function()
{
     ...
     //End of use
     atomic_store(&v, 1);
     ...
}
thread_2_function()
{
     ...
     atomic_store(&v, 2);
     ...
}
thread_3_function()
{
     ...
     atomic_load(&v);
     if (i == 1)  {...}
     else if (i == 2) {...} 
     ...
}
```

Comment: What specific atomic operations are you talking about? Usually one does not lock atomic variables when using them, since they provide concurrency guarantees themselves. Those guarantees do not usually depend on the number of cpu cores. But it depends on the details, which you don't provide.

Comment: @Paul Hankin I'm sorry. I'm just beginning to learn atomic operation. I'm not sure what “the details” you mentioned are, because my current requirement is that multiple threads access the same atomic variable at the same time.

Comment: You don't have to lock atomic variables. That's the reason why you use atomics instead of normal variables. The CPU takes care of everything for you.

Comment: On Intel, plain old value types become "atomic" by using a combination of LOCK and XCHG operations.  Just remember this - atomics are no substitute for using real lock/mutex semantics in your code. For example let's imagine the moment `atomic_load` returns inside `thread_3`. At that moment,  there is a context switch to another thread that invokes `atomic_store`. That invalidates the value of `v` that just got loaded by the other thread.  99% of the time, your really want to use a thread-safe lock around a block of code instead of cleverness at manipulating a single variable with atomics

Comment: @selbie Yes, there is the kind of situation you said. It seems that in thread 3,I still need to lock before using V and release the lock after using v. like mutex.

Comment: @guoyanzhang - correct.  And if you use a mutex correctly, there's usually not much need to declare the variables protected by that lock as atomic.

Comment: @selbie it does not make much sense to use atomic_load with locking in your case. In this case you would need to lock all stores as well. Besides locking it after the load will cause races. Instead you should use the value which is *returned* by the load: `val = atomic_load(&v);` The return value will be unchallenged in the thread_3.

Comment: @Serge - Well yes, of course.  But I got the sense that the OP really wanted locks - because using atomics for concurrent programming is a more nuanced thing. Those new to concurrent programming can be lulled into a false sense of security around thread-safety thinking atomics are a full solution.